# Single Term-Multiple word Synonyms mapping not working in solr

Tags: java, solr, synonym

I'm trying to set up some basic synonyms in Solr. I'm facing an issue with below entry in synonyms.txt file

Cricket=> Twenty20, One day International,Test Cricket

When a user searches for cricket, user gets back documents containing One day International but not for Twenty20 and Test Cricket.

How do I get results for other two keywords?

Schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: can you share schema snippet where you declared the synonymfilter?

Comment: @SumeetSharma i included it in the question just now..

Comment: https://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/07/12/solution-for-multi-term-synonyms-in-lucenesolr-using-the-auto-phrasing-tokenfilter/ checkout the work around suggested in this blog ..'

Comment: did you try out something?